# Displaying EUnit code coverage in Emacs

Tags: emacs, erlang, rebar, eunit

I am using Rebar to build my erlang project and want to integrate it more tightly with Emacs. I found that if I add `{cover_print_enabled, true}.` to my rebar config file I get code coverage in the build output.

However there is also an option `cover_export_enabled` which outputs a binary file of some form. Is there an emacs plugin to parse that file and color code my code to show what code is covered by tests?

I really don't like having to switch to a browser to see code coverage.

Comment: Can you provide an example of output file - does it consists from binary data, or it's text data with ANSI colors? You can also display HTML in the Emacs, using the w3m or other package

Comment: Binary, as I said in the post. Yes I could display the HTML in emacs but I really want to overlay it with my editing enviroment

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, there is no such plugin.

The exported cover data file can be read as follows:

1. Read one byte, giving the length of the next term; let's call it `N`.
2. Read `N` bytes in Erlang binary term format.  This can be decoded with [binary_to_term/1](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/erlang.html#binary_to_term-1).
3. If the term from step 2 is of the form `{'$size',X}`, then read `X` bytes and decode as a term.  (This happens when the binary representation of the term is longer than 255 bytes.)
4. Continue from step 1, until end of file.

Distel has an Emacs Lisp implementation of `binary_to_term` called [erlext-read-obj in erlext.el](https://github.com/massemanet/distel/blob/master/elisp/erlext.el#L259).

I haven't looked into what to do with the terms in the file, once decoded, but hopefully this is enough to get someone started.  Read [lib/tools/src/cover.erl](https://github.com/erlang/otp/blob/master/lib/tools/src/cover.erl) if in doubt.

Answer (score 0):

Just added this feature to `rebar.el` in commit https://github.com/leoliu/rebar.el/commit/9ba8699ff6310721226b93341e62491ebfd0ee99

Leo